# how to change history command copy content more than 10 result?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, cron, history

In cron file i am using code like this

```
*/1 * * * * history > myhistory.log
```

I am using this command to show my last "history" results in another file

```
tail -l /var/log/myhistory.log
```

but result have only last 10 history commands like this:

```
/dev/pts/1 printf
/dev/pts/1 date
/dev/pts/1 printf
/dev/pts/1 date
/dev/pts/1 printf
/dev/pts/1 clear
/dev/pts/1 printf
/dev/pts/1 date
/dev/pts/1 printf
/dev/pts/1 date
```

I want to see all history results about more than 100 command here, but here show me only 10 last results.

How can i get all of history results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tail only shows the last 10 results. However, you can use the -n[number] option to show however many you want. for example :

```
tail -n100 /var/log/myhistory.log
```

this will show you the last 100 commands.

Comment: Was just going to mention the -x syntax

Answer (score 0):

`tail` exactly outputs the last ten lines, and `head` the first ten

to output all content try replacing it with `cat` [instead](http://www.hillspet.com/en/us/cat-care/behavior-appearance/cat-tail-language)